# How to scroll div to get all dynamically loading items?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrap site https://cs.money to get all items and prices but my script loading only first 180 skins and I have no idea how to load all items. Can someone give me a tip what I should use to load all the items and what is best approach to do this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://cs.money/en')
time.sleep(5)
asd = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("item")
qwe = []
for a in asd:
    if a.get_attribute("ar"):
        qwe.append([a.get_attribute("hash"), a.get_attribute("cost"), a.get_attribute("ar")])
    else:
        qwe.append([a.get_attribute("hash"), a.get_attribute("cost"), ])
driver.close()

lables = ['name', 'price', 'float_bonus']
dataas = pd.DataFrame.from_records(qwe, columns=lables)
```

Comment: its because of ajax feature of the application , until you scroll to the last element you cannot access the next elements.

Comment: Step 1. You can get the first set of the element and store it in `set` 
Step 2. Then scroll to the last element 
Step 3. Repeat step 1 and 2 , until last element of the `div`

Comment: I just added `for i in range(10):

    element = driver.find_element_by_id("inventory_bot")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(0,document.documentElement.scrollHeight-100);", element)` it works but is very very slow any idea how to make it faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `time.sleep(5)` you could add:

```
for i in range(0,5): # here you will need to tune to see exactly how many scrolls you need
  driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 400)')
  time.sleep(1)
```

The above is a general solution when you need to scroll dynamic content on a page.

In your case I think the best approach, time wise, would be to scroll into view always the last element you could use:

```
for i in range(0,25): # here you will need to tune to see exactly how many scrolls you need
  driver.execute_script('items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");i = items[items.length-1];i.scrollIntoView();')
```

this is the JS snippet you can try in the browser console:

```
items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");i = items[items.length-1];i.scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Your code is little bit faster then mine but still scraping whole inventory took me 10+ minutes, so i think i will try replicate the ajax request and get all data as json, its should be faster if its possible.

Comment: EDIT: i just found https://cs.money/load_bots_inventory?hash= when i was checking requests after refreshing inventory, so now it will be fast and easy tu get all items data. Thanks all for help